# How to highlight or change the color of a DataGridview row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have database table

```
    Inbox(id,accountid,emailfrom,emailsubject,emailbody, recieveddate,attachment, read(bool)
```

i have added it to the form through table adapter and show it in a grid view. working fine. but onething that i want to do is when the  read column value is false i want to change the color of the gridrow or highlight that row?

kindly guid me how i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this link [How do I specially color only the current cell of a readonly datagrid](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/30/how-do-i-specially-color-only-the-current-cell-of-a-read-only-datagrid.aspx) answer your question? I discusses how to create a custom column style overriding its paint method to change the background color.